# Какое причастие нужно в предложении: действительное или страдательное?

Tags: грамотная-речь, причастия

Какое причастие — действительное или страдательное — нужно писать в следующем предложении?

*Этому способствуют программы, **реализующиеся** (реализуемые) на территории округа за счет средств бюджетов вышестоящего уровня.*

Comment: Отметьте ответ галочкой, если он вам помог.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможны обе варианта, но слово ***реализуемый*** используется значительно чаще, чем ***реализующийся***: частотность 57:7. Из этого можно сделать вывод, что **страдательная форма кажется пользователям более уместной.** Сравним: реализующиеся программы и реализуемые программы. Кажется, что активное начало не очень подходит к этому сочетанию: как будто они сами собой реализуются.

Примеры:

Нефтегазовые проекты, массово **реализуемые** сегодня в центре российской Арктики ― Ямало-Ненецком автономном округе, относятся к высшему сегменту мировой технологической мысли. [Вадим Пономарев. Прорыв в Арктику // «Эксперт», 2014]

А уже **реализующиеся** сегодня в Москве проекты сноса хрущевок и строительства на их месте нового жилого фонда еще и выгодны застройщикам. [Елена Новомлинская. Реконструкция пятиэтажек в Москве (1996) // «Коммерсантъ-Daily», 1996.01.20]

**А вот пример, где активное начало (для процессов) вполне уместно:**

Уравнения (22) описывают все существенные особые случаи, **реализующиеся** на малых временах и обусловленные диффузионными процессами, протекающими в пороупругих телах ....

Примерно то же можно видеть и в остальных примерах (из семи вариантов, найденных в Нацкорпусе).

Answer (score 5):

Смотря какой смысл вы хотите выразить. "Реализующиеся" будет однозначно указывать, что программы уже находятся *в процессе реализации*. Слово же "реализуемые" в данном контексте может иметь двоякий смысл: а) те, которые *уже реализуются*; б) такие, которые *могут быть реализованы* за счёт средств бюджета (они могут оставаться в планах, поскольку программа и до её реализации может "способствовать" чему-то - её учитывают и т. п.).